# How to join a KSQL table and a stream on a non row key column

Tags: ksqldb, confluent-platform

I am using community edition of confluent Platform version 5.4.1. I did not find any CLI command to print the KSQL Server version but when I enter KSQL what I get to see can be found in the attached screenshot. [image]

I have a geofence table -

```
CREATE TABLE GEOFENCE (GEOFENCEID INT, 
                       FLEETID VARCHAR, 
                       GEOFENCECOORDINATES VARCHAR) 
                 WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='MONGODB-GEOFENCE', 
                       VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', 
                       KEY= 'GEOFENCEID');
```

The data is coming to Geofence KSQL table from Kafka MongoDB source connector whenever an insert or update operation is performed on the geofence MongoDB collection from a web application supported by a REST API. The idea behind making geofence a table is that since tables are mutable it would hold the updated geofence information and since the insert or update operation will not be very frequent and whenever there are changes in the Geofence MongoDB collection they will get updated on the Geofence KSQL table since the key here is GeofenceId.

I have a live stream of vehicle position -

```
CREATE STREAM VEHICLE_POSITION (VEHICLEID INT, 
                                FLEETID VARCHAR, 
                                LATITUDE DOUBLE, 
                                LONGITUDE DOUBLE) 
                          WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='VEHICLE_POSITION', 
                          VALUE_FORMAT='JSON')
```

I want to join table and stream like this -

```
CREATE STREAM VEHICLE_DISTANCE_FROM_GEOFENCE AS 
    SELECT  GF.GEOFENCEID, 
            GF.FLEETID, 
            VP.VEHICLEID, 
            GEOFENCE_UDF(GF.GEOFENCECOORDINATES, VP.LATITUDE, VP.LONGITUDE)  
       FROM GEOFENCE GF 
             LEFT JOIN VEHICLE_POSITION VP 
                ON GF.FLEETID = VP.FLEETID;
```

But KSQL will not allow me to do because I am performing join on `FLEETID` which is a non row key column.Though this would have been possible in SQL but how do I achieve this in KSQL?

Note: According to my application's business logic Fleet Id is used to combine Geofences and Vehicles belonging to a fleet.

Sample data for table -

```
INSERT INTO GEOFENCE
(GEOFENCEID INT, FLEETID VARCHAR, GEOFENCECOORDINATES VARCHAR) 
VALUES (10, 123abc, 52.4497_13.3096);
```

Sample data for stream -

```
INSERT INTO VEHICLE_POSITION 
(VEHICLEID INT, FLEETID VARCHAR, LATITUDE DOUBLE, LONGITUDE DOUBLE) 
VALUES (1289, 125abc, 57.7774, 12.7811):
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show the two tables structure (e.g. `DESCRIBE x` output), and sample rows from each? It will make it much easier to follow and help

Comment: ksqlDB doesn't _yet_ support non-key joins. See https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/4424.

However, as Robin suggests, if you provide more details there may be an alternative.

Can you update your question with the two `CREATE` statements and sample data, and your ksqlDB version, please?

Comment: @AndrewCoates Please have a look at the edited question.

Comment: That's much better, though some sample data would help.  Specifically, what's the relationship between geofenceid and fleetid?  Can the same fleetid be set for more than one geofenceid, or is there a one-to-one mapping between the two?

Comment: @AndrewCoates 
A fleet id can have one or many geofences. A fleet can have one or many vehicles.
Sample data added in question.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem what you need is a table of FENCEID to GEOFENCECOORDINATES. You could use such a table to join to your VEHICLE_POSITION stream to get the result you need.

So, how do you get a table of FENCEID to GEOFENCECOORDINATES?

The simple answer is that you can't with your current table definition!  You declare the table as having only the `GEOFENCEID` as the primary key. Yet a fleetId can have many fences.  To be able to mode this, both `GEOFENCEID` and `FENCEID` would need to be part of the primary key of the table.

Consider the example:

```
INSERT INTO GEOFENCE VALUES (10, 'fleet-1', 'coords-1');
INSERT INTO GEOFENCE VALUES (10, 'fleet-2', 'coords-2');
```

Are running these two inserts the table would contain only a single row, with key `10` and value `'fleet-2', 'coords-2'`.

Even if we could somehow capture the above information in a table, consider what happens if there is a tombstone in the topic, because the first row had been deleted from the source Mongo table. A tombstone is the key, (`10`), and a `null` value. ksqlDB would then remove the row from its table with key `10`, leaving an empty table.

This is the crux of your problem!

First, you'll need to configure the source connector to get both the fence id and fleet id into the key of the messages.

Next, you'll need to access this in ksqlDB. Unfortunately, ksqlDB, as of version 0.10.0 / CP 6.0.0 doesn't support multiple key columns, though [this is being worked on](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/projects/9) soon.

In the meantime, if you key is a JSON document containing the two key fields, e.g.

```
{
   "GEOFENCEID": 10,
   "FLEETID": "fleet-1"
}
```

Then you can import it into ksqlDB as a STRING:

```
-- 5.4.1 syntax:
-- ROWKEY will contain the JSON document, containing GEOFENCEID and FLEETID
CREATE TABLE GEOFENCE (
    GEOFENCECOORDINATES VARCHAR
  ) 
  WITH (
     KAFKA_TOPIC='MONGODB-GEOFENCE', 
     VALUE_FORMAT='JSON'
  );

-- 6.0.0 syntax:
CREATE TABLE GEOFENCE (
    JSONKEY STRING PRIMARY KEY, 
    GEOFENCECOORDINATES VARCHAR
  ) 
  WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC='MONGODB-GEOFENCE', 
    VALUE_FORMAT='JSON'
  );
```

With the table now correctly defined you can use `EXTRACTJSONFIELD` to access the data in the JSON key and collect all the fence coordinates using `COLLECT_SET`.  I'm not 100% sure this would on 5.4.1, (see how you get on), but will on 6.0.0.

```
-- 6.0.0 syntax
CREATE TABLE FLEET_COORDS AS
   SELECT
    EXTRACTJSONFIELD(JSONKEY, '$.FLEETID') AS FLEETID,
    COLLECT_SET(GEOFENCECOORDINATES)
   FROM GEOFENCE
   GROUP BY EXTRACTJSONFIELD(JSONKEY, '$.FLEETID');
```

This will give you a table of fleetId to a set of fence coordinates. You can use this to join to your vehicle position stream. Of course, your `GEOFENCE_UDF` udf will need to accept an `ARRAY<STRING>` for the fence coordinates, as there may be many.

Good luck!